# Unable to access elements present in BottomSheetDialog

Tags: android

I have BottomSheetDialog present in my activity and I have button in Bottom sheet how can I access that button in my activity.

But I am getting error when app starts:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
    at com.example.bottomsheetdialog.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:26)
```

Below is my layout:

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:padding="16dp">

 <Button
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="40dp"
   android:text="OPEN"
   android:textColor="#fff"
   android:id="@+id/open"
   android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
   android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**custom_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="16dp">

 <Button
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/but"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:text="SUBMIT"
    android:textColor="#fff"/>

 </LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button open,but;
BottomSheetDialog bottomSheetDialog;
View dialogLayout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    bottomSheetDialog = new BottomSheetDialog(MainActivity.this);
    open = findViewById(R.id.open);
    but = dialogLayout.findViewById(R.id.but);

    open.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            View dialogLayout = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_layout,null);
            bottomSheetDialog.setContentView(dialogLayout);
            bottomSheetDialog.setDismissWithAnimation(true);
            bottomSheetDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
            bottomSheetDialog.show();
        }
    });

    but.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Hello",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
  }
}
```

Someone please let me know what I am doing wrong.Any help would be appreciated.

**THANKS**

Comment: because   dialogLayout is null. You have to initalize first and then look for the view. So move this inside onClick of Button(open) - dialogLayout.findViewById(R.id.but) after you have inflated the layout

Comment: How can I do this please provide some code.